# What is the name of this effect? How is it achieved?

Tags: photoshop-effects, animation

I was told that this was created using a single image though it looks like two images. How is it possible to create an effect like this?
[Posted by Sammy Rawal on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BvCSkkHgIGO/)

Comment: To me it just looks like a very short movie which is looped while zooming in and out.

Comment: Or it's a series of images taken at the same time from slightly different angles with some special gadget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Parallax Effect, 2.5D

The **2.5D** or **parallax effect** is an incredibly popular method for bringing images to life when editing video with mixed media, such as photos, newspaper articles, and graphics. "Parallax" is rooted in the Greek word "parallaxis", which translates literally as "alternation". In imagery and animation, the parallax effect is when the movement of the background appears slower than the foreground to produce an illusion of depth. This alternating motion between the foreground and the background produces a feeling of changing perspectives that pulls the viewer in.

There are many methods and tools to create the parallax effect..

[How to Give Your Still Photos a 2.5D Parallax Effect in Photoshop](https://petapixel.com/2017/08/09/give-still-photos-2-5d-parallax-effect-photoshop/)

[How to Create a 2.5D Parallax Effect on Images in Photoshop CC](https://blog.pond5.com/16853-create-2-5d-parallax-effect-images-photoshop-cc/)

[2.5D Parallax Effect Tutorial in Photoshop](http://www.michaelvanarey.com/blog/2016/4/28/bing-your-photos-to-life-using-25d-parallax-effect-using-photoshop)

Comment: Thank you. I think the technique is the same as what you've mentioned here. Looks like the original video was created by looping two frames, first the original and the second one where the background (and foreground?) is slightly altered using the parallax effect.